# Can disk drives from a PV MD3220i be moved to a PE R420, and vice-versa?

Tags: dell-poweredge, sas

I've read that some Dell hardware (mostly storage enclosures these days) are picky about drive firmware (i.e. Dell certified drives). But I can't find a definitive answer about swapping Dell-certified drives between servers and storage enclosures.

All systems are currently running with the drives they originally came with, and all systems are using the same kind of drives (300GB SAS 6Gbps 10k 2.5", if that matters).
Of course we don't expect to keep the drives content.

Can we move disks from an MD3220i to R420 servers?
...and...
Can we move disks from R420 servers to an MD3220i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MD3220i requires disks with dell firmware, so yes you can move the drives from your servers and vice versa, but not other makes of drive.

Some optional controllers in the R420 had a similar restriction however this was lifted.  If you update a controller giving this error to the latest firmware it will log a warning that they are not supported but allow them to function as normal.